# JQUERY + location.reload() callback

Tags: jquery

I'm using a location.reload() with JQUERY to refresh when a user changes language.
I wanted to ask if its possible to have a callback after location.reload()?

I kind of assume not as it refreshes the page but it might be possible.

Please let me know.

thx

Comment: I dont think that it will be posible.can you explain the usage of it? so, we can think of a alternative.

Comment: there is no method as `reload()` in jquery core lib, please elaborate your question

Comment: meant location.reload() - as in the subject...

Comment: `.reload()` is not a jQuery function, it's a standard JS thing in the `window.location` object. No callback possible, but there are some potential alternatives depending on what you wanted the callback to do. If you could update your question to explain _why_ you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that it is, however I believe that there is another solution to your problem. Cookies. If you were to use a cookie to indicate that the user had changed languages you can then perform the logic you want upon seeing that cookie. That approach could work. If you needed to have early javascript interception you might need to have your javascript at the top of your html page and outside of any document.load or document ready functinons so that it evaluates quickly.

This does seem like hackery to me, so althought I have proposed a work around for your question I dont stand behind the recommending the approach.

Comment: A very simple solution would: location = location.href +"?langChanged". On page load, just check for that querystring.