# Refresh page on button click and after that call an function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to refresh an web page on button click and after page refresh call an function.
But its reverse is not happening i.e. first call the function and after that refresh the page.

This is what I have tried:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function restartall(){
        $('#text').append('hello');
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:document.location.reload();">
<button onclick="restartall()">Referash Map</button></a>
<div id="text"></div>
```

please solve this query.

Comment: why don't you use ajax instead of refreshing the page ?

Comment: If you use jQuery why don't you bind events with jQuery and instead use unsafe methods like `onclick` parameter ?

Comment: Could you explain why you need to refresh the page?

Comment: If you really want to execute a specific function after page refresh after the button was clicked, you can create a cookie when the button is clicked, then on page load, try to read the cookie, and if it exists, execute your custom function. (Or keep a flag in your code behind and read it)

Comment: Check my answer. I think it will work for you !

Comment: See mine.. it does call function only when reloaded with click on your link... in all other cases it will skip that method...

Answer (score 3):

use below code

```
<body onload="onrefresh();">

<a href="javascript:myfun();">

function myfun(){
    window.location.search += '&reload=true';
}
function onrefresh(){
 if(gup("reload")=='true'){
    // DO whatever want to do. 
  }
}


function gup( name ){
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");  
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";  
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );  
    var results = regex.exec( window.location.href ); 
    if( results == null )
        return "";  
    else
      return results[1];
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was going to make, just with `if (window.location.indexOf('reload')>-1)`

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="javascript:abc();"><script>function restartall() {
    $('#text').append('hello');
}

function abc() {
    document.location.reload();
    restartall();

}</script>
```

Comment: I thought he wanted `restartAll` to be executed _after_ `reload()`

Comment: you said it should "first call the function and after that refresh the page", that exactly what this code does. So what anything extra you want to do ? just clearify.

Comment: so change the order of functions calling. Look my updated answer. Is'nt it right ?

Answer (score 1):

When you reload page you're loosing JavaScript call stack. You would have to append some parameter to URL or [use cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8722222/2319383).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
    function restartall(){
        $('#text').append('hello');
        document.location.reload();
    }
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="restartall()" value="Referash Map" />
<div id="text"></div>
```