# On function call go to specific page and perform action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I looked around stackoverflow but was unable to find anything satisfactory to my need. So here's my question:

I want to call a function on button click. For this i did

```
  $( "#btn_id" ).click(function myFun() {
     // whatever needs to be done
  });
```

But the thing is the caller button is global(available though-out) to my site for design needs  however the function can be performed only on the home page.

Is there any way to first redirect to home-page and if already there, reload the page and then run the function.

I'm able to reload page and then call the function following this: [Refresh page on button click and after that call an function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581414/refresh-page-on-button-click-and-after-that-call-an-function). However the problem with this method is the function gets called automatically on all refresh which is not required. It should be triggered only though that button click.

Comment: Send a hidden input with the click on the button and execute the function on the new page within an `if isset $_POST` check in php.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#btn_id").on("click", function() { myFun(); }); // more up-to-date
```

you could set a flag (POST / GET) - checking whether it is set or not (so whether your site is refreshed by button-click or by a *normal*-refresh

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the function in button click event then why you call the function in refresh.

Or call the function like below..

```
$( "#btn_id" ).click(function {
     myFun();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the url of the page you are on . using `document.URL;` and check a condition on the function you have to run on homepage. Something like this

```
    $( "#btn_id" ).click(function myFun() {
       if(document.URL == "http://www.myhome.com/home")
            {
            document.location.reload();
             }
       else {
           window.location = "http://www.myhome.com/home";
           document.location.reload();
           restartall();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
But the thing is the caller button is global(available though-out) 
to my site for design needs however the function can be performed 
only on the home page.

Is there any way to first redirect to home-page and if already 
there, reload the page and then run the function.
```

Why will you redirect the page if you can select the element without using the global button `id` and give it a class different to other page like

```
<input type = "button" value = "fire me" class = "some_class" id = "btn_id">
```

then make event listener like what you did but change the selector like

```
$( ".some_class" ).click(
  function myFun() {
 // whatever needs to be done
```

});

EDIT:
Things had been shift differently here because it uses an `id` for design purposes. 
FYI. In designing your multiple page use a class.

Answer (score 0):

> calling function after refresh page is not possible because after refreshing page the queue can be reset so it is possible using only cookies or call function in home page load if it is in another page use, find which page it is like

```
if(location.pathname!=="home.html")
{
   window.location.href = 'home.html';
}
```